# manytomany Implementation in Django (admin issue)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, admin, manytomanyfield

I've spent a lot of time reading through the other questions on this subject and the Django docs. I'm relatively new to python and completely new to django and webdesign.

I'm attempting to set up the admin site so that the leader of the project I'm working on can enter/edit the data she needs. 
I'm trying to implement a manytomany relationship between two models: Subordinate Metaphor and Myth.

models.py

```
class Mytheme(models.Model):
    myth_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mytheme = models.CharField("Mytheme",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    superord_myth = models.CharField("Superordinate Myth", max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    myth_dhuy = models.CharField("D'huy Myth",max_length=600, blank=True, null=True)
    deities_involved = models.CharField("Deities Involved",max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    myth = models.CharField("Myth",max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    myth_comment = models.CharField("Comment",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'mytheme'
        ordering = ['myth_id']
        verbose_name = 'Mytheme'

 class Subordinatemet(models.Model):

    submet_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    submetaphor = models.CharField("Subordinate Metaphor", max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_type = models.CharField("Type",max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_semanticfield = models.CharField("Semantic Field",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True) 
    sub_metanet_no = models.BigIntegerField("Metanet Number",blank=True, null=True)
    sub_metanet_frame = models.CharField("Metanet Frame",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_dhuy_no = models.BigIntegerField("D'huy Number",blank=True, null=True)
    sub_dyson_ref = models.CharField("Dyson Reference",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_johnlakoff_ref = models.CharField("Johnson/Lakoff Reference",max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_bibliography = models.CharField("Bibliography",max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_comment = models.CharField("Comment", max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    ordinacy = models.SmallIntegerField("Ordinacy",blank=True, null=True)
    myths = models.ManyToManyField(Mytheme)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'subordinatemet'
        ordering = ['submet_id']
        verbose_name = 'Subordinate Metaphor'
```

When I go into the admin site and try to add a new entry for Subordinate Metaphor, I am treated to an error after I click save:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 575, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1554, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 62, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 58, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1451, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1492, in _changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1049, in save_related
    form.save_m2m()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 439, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1619, in save_form_data
    getattr(instance, self.attname).set(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 955, in set
    old_ids = set(self.using(db).values_list(self.target_field.target_field.attname, flat=True))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 178, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1068, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "subordinatemet_myths" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT "mytheme"."myth_id" FROM "mytheme" INNER JOIN "subordina...
```

I see what it is trying to do, but maybe I don't understand what's going on behind the scenes enough to understand -why- it is trying to do that.

My questions are:

- What is happening here-- is the system creating a "ghost table" of the relationships between the two models?
- How do I fix this so that I can use the admin interface to add relationships between Subordinatemet and Mytheme?

This is my first post, so if anyone needs more information, please tell me and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Have you forgot to propagate changes in the models to the database?

Comment: @RomanKonoval I've run all the migrations, but I'm not sure if I have to change anything in settings/in postgresql to enable that manytomany field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does create a table that stores many-to-many relation:

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to
>   represent the many-to-many relationship.

The error message shows that the table is not there. Most probably you have added the field to the model but haven't propagated changes to the database.

To do that you need:

1. generated required migrations first using `django-admin makemigrations` command
2. apply migrations using `django-admin migrate` command

Check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/) for more details about how to use migrations.

Comment: Thank you so much for this-- you're right. Django hasn't actually been making any of my migrations, so I built a couple of the tables manually to it's specification and that worked. I tried running the django-admin makemigrations, but I'm getting a modulenotfound error for my site. Ah well. Next challenge.